# Create something like Citrix XenDesktop using Xen

Tags: virtualization, xen, vdi, xendesktop, paravirtualization

I am doing an academic project. I want to deploy a **Virtual Desktop Infrastructure** for my college. So, is there any way/guideline to make something like XenDesktop using Xen on a Linux Distro from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind switching to KVM, [oVirt](http://ovirt.org) is an out of the box VDI and SVI system. It is actually used for VDI at academic institutions